# C++ URL decode with utf8 characters error

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I can`t find any solution to my problem with utf8 characters inside an encoded url while in c++ visual studio.

I have this url encoded string :

```
//Encoded
%5C%CE%A4%CE%B5%CF%83%CF%84%5C
//Decoded
\Τεστ\
```

In any online encoder and decoder with php functions the above encoded string will give you the decoded correct string but in c++ visual studio any try i made with decoding url codes failed.

I use Unicode Character Set in my project and i retrieve this encoded url as : (p.s. i cant change the way i recieve it - it is an encoded url std:string)

```
std:string EncURL = "%5C%CE%A4%CE%B5%CF%83%CF%84%5C";
```

i then try with many decoding function from the internet to make it readable and use it but it always returns me chinese characters instead of the correct ones.
Below is a function among many that i tried and it works only if the encoded url has no utf8 characters inside.

```
string url_decode(string src){
  string ret;
  char ch;
  int i,ii;
  for(i=0; i<src.length(); i++){
     if(int(src[i]) == 37){
       sscanf(src.substr(i+1,2).c_str(), "%x", &ii);
       ch = static_cast<char>(ii);
       ret += ch;
       i = i+2;
     }else{
        ret += src[i];
     }
  }
  return (ret);
}
```

Will anyone give me a good way or solution of making URLdecoding function that will work properly even with utf8 characters inside ?
Any type or any way is used after the std:string EncURL doesnt matter, i just need to have a properly urldecoder in c++ for the string i recieve.

---------- Update

The reason that i need to convert is obvious for URL opening or filepath opening (folder or file) from within c++ but the encoded URL string is coming as is encoded inside C++ from outside the application.(database, web, chat, file, etc etc) 
So i need to decode it in utf8 since i need to correct that non latin part for multilanguage purposes and then to use the decoded utf8 string for the reason is needed.

This update may helps for non converting it just for wcout or cout but for its target puprose which i really need and nothing yet is working as it should.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you checking the UTF-8 decoded string?  Windows is natively UTF-16 and you will have to convert to that before outputting it (or even looking at it in the debugger).  UTF-8 strings will get displayed as MBCS if you don't convert them.

Comment: Is it the decoding that is the problem or are you using `utf8` where it is not expected?

Comment: How do you know it failed? What test did you do? Can you post *that* code?

Comment: i only get an encoded url string (that string anywhere else decoded gives correct output) in mvs it doesnt.As output lets consider a simple cout << decodedURL or wcout << decodedURL but i havent manage to make it show the correct decoded url yet, cant check anything from the encoded string as recieved i need that encoded string to decoded but show me in a cout << or wcout << for example the correct decoded string

Comment: You should try: `std:string EncURL = u8".....";`

Comment: @Brandon Any other way ? cause i can`t use the u8 literal in visual studio 2013 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: On Windows I don't think the terminal that `cout` writes to accepts `utf-8`. You may need to convert it to `UTF-16` or `UCS-2` and use `std::wcout` (I'm not a Windows expert)

Comment: There are tons of questions on StackOverflow that deal with how to display UTF output in a console on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question since i found the solution and for anyone else is using std::string and want to have utf8 characters correct may come in handy.

The solution is to convert the encoded url std::string to std::wstring and then use any URLdecoder to decode the wstring.
The decoded wstring is always correct as in php online url encode and decode.
So you can use the decoded wstring as you like.

For output even in windows console application you can use 
Messabox to see the correct output with wstring

Comment: I didnot understand when you said any URLDecoder. Can you post your code.